# Could my answer be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-answers

I answered [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/325235/169736), with an answer about the line:

> well, currently the app don't have such function, but you have this alternatives.

The alternatives don't fit all the asker requirements (I even proposed to do a feature request to the developers), but is a valid (due current inherent limitations) solution. I can't vote to undelete it since was mod hammered, so only a mod can undelete it.

Comment: The answer has been undeleted now that it has been edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As you say](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7174/could-my-answer-be-undeleted#comment11299_7175), [your answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/328350/22949), at least *in its [recently edited form](https://askubuntu.com/posts/328350/revisions)*, does answer the question:

> There is no shortcut that allows you to change the profile within the
>   terminal (without navigating the menus as you said in comments),
>   without the use of the GUI.

This does the work of [Oli's suggestion](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/7175/22949) that "No, there is no shortcut for this" may be an appropriate answer to the question.

So you're right, at least with respect to the current version of your answer. Your answer should be undeleted. The OP and other users can always downvote it if they think it's not good.

(That is not to say that deleting your answer was necessarily wrong at the time, since that was befor the subsequent edit.)

If I saw the current version of your deleted answer first (rather than this meta question first), I would probably have custom-flagged it to request undeletion. (Since we already have this meta question where it can be discussed, that's likely unnecessary, though.)

Answer (score 2):

The OP is being picky and your answer doesn't appear to answer exactly what they're looking for, that is, a way of switching profile without changing terminal instance. They have accounted for (essentially) what you're suggesting in their own question.

It seems the answer should be "No, there is no shortcut for this." and that would be a valid answer, if true.

Comment: I added as an opening: *There is no keyboard shortcut, nor call, that allows you ...*, so, from the very start (after edits), I was saying, "no, there's no way to do this".

Comment: @Oli "No, there is no shortcut for this" (with explanation) would be a valid answer even if false, in the sense that it would be an answer to the question that was asked, and thus a poor candidate for deletion (though a good candidate for downvoting, if it were false).